# IOS App Created Wholly with HTML 5 - Input lag... fixable?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, uiwebview

Like many others, I have decided to build my app via HTML 5, with limited native code (some of the UI and whatnot). However, I have run into a critical problem related to the UX. It seems that input boxes and buttons created via HTML 5 always have a longer lag time in recognizing their click event then the native interface.

For example:

A button created using UIButton and native code, when pressed, will immediately register the click and immediately flip me to the next page.

However...

A button created through HTML5 in the UIWebView always has a 500-1500 MS lag time before registering the click... which results in a very disjointed and fragmented user experience.

My question to you... is there any way to solve this problem via actually pushing the users touch event quicker somehow, or even by faking it to make it *look* like the HTML5 input boxes are giving instant feedback?

Thank you very much for your assistance everyone. :)

Comment: Check this out in Safari by entering the same URL you are using in your UIWebView. If it's faster then it's likely that slow down is caused by the UIWebView's lack of JIT compiler. Apple has done this deliberately because of security reasons. Having said that (and not having done any html 5 myself) I would expect that a compiled native UI would always be more responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this could be because MobileSafari has the double-tap gesture for zooming, which means that a single tap will have a slight delay while the system waits for a possible second tap.

A possible solution using touchStart/touchMove/touchEnd events is detailed [here](http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone)

Comment: Wossname, i am testing out your solution right now.. will get back with the results.

Comment: Wossname, excellent answer thank you. By handling the onclickstart/end events instead of the touch event, I was able to decrease the lag from 400+ ms to 60-90 ms. The entire UX is *completely* different now. I sincerely hope others with my problem that are creating their own HTML5-based apps will look here to be able to work around the horrible touch response time.

Comment: @Wossname: I have used the [NoClickDelay](http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone) approach and I got rid of the delay. However I had the following two issues. 1. I had to add `onclick="this.focus()"` on textfields and `onclick="this.submit()"` on the submit button. 2. The user could no longer set the curser in the textfield using the long-press gesture. Did you experience the same problem?